# How to Copy file to specific directory & Set Filename, Extension using OpenDialog in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, save, save-image

I have a `OpenDialog` in my wpf application where the user can choose file and save to folder. I want to Save the image to specific folder and set the filename & extenstion on button click in wpf.

Folder structure:

- -MyAppDirectory
  --ContactImages

  -1.jpg

**When i execute following code it create the "`ContactImages`" direcotry in Bin folder and not in Application main direcotry. Any idea? & how to get file extension of uploaded file in wpf & set file name?**

in xaml.cs file:

```
private void imgContactImage_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            string folderpath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\ContactImages\\";
            op.Title = "Select a picture";
            op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
                "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
                "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";

            bool? myResult;
            myResult = op.ShowDialog();
            if (myResult != null && myResult == true)
            {

                imgContactImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
                if (!Directory.Exists(folderpath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath);
                }

                //System.IO.File.Copy(op.FileName,filename);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can rewrite the snippet provided as

```
OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
string folderpath = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.FullName + "\\ContactImages\\";
op.Title = "Select a picture";
op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
            "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
            "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";

bool? myResult;
myResult = op.ShowDialog();
if (myResult != null && myResult == true)
{
  imgContactImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
  if (!Directory.Exists(folderpath))
  {
     Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath);
  }
  string filePath = folderpath + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(op.FileName);
  System.IO.File.Copy(op.FileName, filePath, true);
 }
```

Comment: but, how to copy/upload image to specific folder using System.IO.File.Copy(op.FileName,filename);